# Problems connection new iPhone to Raspberry Pi WiFi

Tags: iphone, wifi, tethering

I have setup a Raspberry Pi 3 as WiFi hotspot at home. For this, my home's WiFi signals it tethered to ethernet with `connmanctl`, showed here :

```
$ sudo connmanctl technologies
/net/connman/technology/p2p
  Name = P2P
  Type = p2p
  Powered = False
  Connected = False
  Tethering = False
/net/connman/technology/bluetooth
  Name = Bluetooth
  Type = bluetooth
  Powered = False
  Connected = False
  Tethering = False
/net/connman/technology/ethernet
  Name = Wired
  Type = ethernet
  Powered = True
  Connected = True
  Tethering = False
/net/connman/technology/wifi
  Name = WiFi
  Type = wifi
  Powered = True
  Connected = False
  Tethering = True
  TetheringIdentifier = xxxx
  TetheringPassphrase = yyyy
```

Android phones, iBook, laptop, iPhone 6s, etc., connects to the WiFi without any difficulty.

With new iPhones : the iPhone sees the WiFi signal, tried to connect, but always complains that the password is incorrect. Even a simple password such as "abcd" gives a "wrong password" response. This behavious has been seen with several iPhones (X, 12, ...) so it doesn't seem to be related to a single phone or model.

These newer iPhones can connect correctly to other WiFi routers, so the problem seems to be between the WiFi setup in the Raspberry Pi 3 and the newer iPhones.

What could be the problem and how can be this be diagnosed further?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *For this, my home's WiFi signals it tethered to ethernet*. What do you mean here?  Is your iPhone tethered or another computer/device?

Comment: Also, what type of security have you implemented?  All of the devices are older (i.e. PowerBook) which have older encryption algorithms.